# set value = 0 while updating record in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, sql-update

im trying to update a column using jsp
here i want my count column value to be updated as zero
count = 0
how can i do that. through this code value is not updating

```
   String code = request.getParameter("code");
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement st=null;
   ResultSet rs = null;
   PreparedStatement ps = null;
   int count = 0;

   try{
     conn = DataBaseConnection.initializeDatabase();
     


    String query1 = null;
     conn.setAutoCommit(false);
     query1 = "update employee set count = ? where code= ' +code+' ";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(query1);
        ps.setInt(1, count);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

here is my record in db
employee table
CODE          VARCHAR2(12)
COUNT          NUMBER(3)

Comment: You haven't quoted your string correctly, currently it will take where code = 'code' instead of actual value of `code` variable. Please correct it.

Comment: i want like this
update employee set validity = 0 where CODE = 'INE001025' ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace

```
"update employee set count = ? where code= ' +code+' ";
```

with

```
"update employee set count = ? where code= '" + code + "'";
```

e.g. if the value of code is `xyz` then after this change, the query will become:

```
"update employee set count = ? where code= 'xyz'";
```

However, I recommend you do it as follows to avoid the [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
query1 = "update employee set count = ? where code= ?";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(query1);
ps.setInt(1, count);
ps.setString(2, code);
```